# Creating a job in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am pretty new to SQL Server 2005. Can someone help me to create a job in SQL Server? This link(http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/sql-server-jobs.html) says to create under the jobs category in managememt tab. But i am not able to find one such category in my SQL Server Management Studio. Is it not possible to create a job using stored procedures or queries?

Thanks,
Geetha

Comment: if you can't see it, you proably don't have sufficient permissions...

Comment: Since I could not find it, the sql server agent is in the sql enterprise manager, and not in the "regular" sql query analyser you'd normally use in the day to day work.

Answer (score 2):

In 2005 it's sql server agent -> jobs

For tsql read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153.aspx)